# Can't push container image into google cloud registry

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-console, google-cloud-registry

I created a Project in the Google-Cloud-Console and created a container registry. Unfortunately i get this error message when pushing:

```
denied: Token exchange failed for project 'myProject'. Caller does not have permission 'storage.buckets.get'. 
To configure permissions, follow instructions at: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control
```

The user i use is the `owner` of the project and also has the role `storage admin` in the IAM. I tried the same with a service account but got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what project is it I assume it's node.js ???

I tried many ways but the one worked for  me is uploading project on private repo
on github with a DockerFile

```js
FROM  node:18.15.0

WORKDIR /server
EXPOSE 3000
COPY . .

RUN npm install --omit=dev

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

and just use github option , authenticate, check docker, after that gc should create your container.
you should see google build for any errors
edit: assuming u want to use  cloud run.  XD